# Getters and setters not working in android

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

```
package com.location.location;

/**
 * Created by user on 14-12-2015.
 */
public class UserDetailsTable {

    String firstName,lastName,userName,password;

    public UserDetailsTable(String firstName, String lastName, String userName,
                            String password) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserDetailsTable() {
        super();
        this.firstName = null;
        this.lastName = null;
        this.userName = null;
        this.password = null;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName;  }
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

I dont know where i am going wrong.... i get three values out of four arguments...the arguments which i get is firstname, lastname,and password,
for username the setter method setuserName says "Method Setter is never used" 
I know this is foolish but I don't see any way out of this.... Please help...

Comment: I assume you are just getting a warning. Are you sure you are using that method somewhere? If not, do you need that setter? Or try writing a little code that calls that method. Does the warning go away?

Comment: It works perfectly fine no error or warning but it doesn't pass anything ,, while debugging i figured out setter function is not being called...I think now much clearer Michael welch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, constructors shouldn't have super(); since the class doesn't extend another one.

next your setter/getter are case sensitive . Try calling setUserName instead

Comment: Thank you I had to call it Explicitly.... Others got it working good as of now...